# Having trouble retreiving data from firebase

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I made an app where a user can sign up and login, when a user first signs up his/her information is stored on firebase. My problem is when I am trying to call the data it is not retreived, instead what I get in the console log is this: -

```
FirebaseListObservable {_isScalar: false, $ref: Reference, source: FirebaseListObservable, operator: ObserveOnOperator}
$ref: Reference {repo: Repo, path: Path, queryParams_: QueryParams, orderByCalled_: false}
operator: ObserveOnOperator {scheduler: ZoneScheduler, delay: 0}
source: FirebaseListObservable {_isScalar: false, _subscribe: ƒ, $ref: Reference}
_isScalar: false
__proto__: Observable
```

I have tried changing which child to call but I get the same result.

Here is part of my Code:-

```
constructor(public afdb: AngularFireDatabase, public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, public alrtCtrl:AlertController) {
    console.log('Hello FirebaseProvider Provider');
    afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      if (user) {this.id = user.uid}
    });
  }

  addUser(user){
      firebase.database().ref('Users').child(user.UID).child('User Details').set(user);
      let alert = this.alrtCtrl.create({
        title:'Sign Up',
        subTitle:'You have signed up successfully',
        buttons:['OK']
      })
      alert.present();
  }

 getUser() {
    return this.afdb.list('/Users/'+this.id+'/User Details/');
 }
```

I am expecting the data to be returned and stored in variable in a different ts file:-

```
constructor(public firebase: FirebaseProvider,public afAuth: AngularFireAuth,public navCtrl: NavController, public auth: AuthProvider) {
    this.user = this.firebase.getUser();
    console.log(this.user);
  }
```

But instead i keep getting the result I showed earlier in console log instead of the actual data.

Comment: I think you are not actually getting the data but just the observable ot the data

Comment: If you do not mind can you give me a simple explanation? Because I am relatively new to app design and Ionic.

Comment: I have seen people recommend using valueChanges(), but this does not work for me and I get this error: https://imgur.com/a/989zsRc

Comment: there is no valueChanges on observable. As I said, the return type here is an observable and thus you have this issue.
can you look into this link
https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md#retrieve-data

Comment: Hi, i have added an answer, can you check that?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like the below code, if nothing works?

```
this.itemsRef = db.list('messages');
// Use snapshotChanges().map() to store the key
this.items = this.itemsRef.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
  return changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }));
});
```

Comment: I did try the code and I instead got an error:- this.itemsRef.snapshotChanges is not a function

Comment: and you did replaced everything with the stuff you wanted right?

Comment: This is my current function I am not sure if there is anything else I need to change  getUser() {
      this.itemsRef = this.afdb.list('/Users/'+this.id+'/User Details/');
      // Use snapshotChanges().map() to store the key
      this.items = this.itemsRef.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
        return changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }));
      });
 }

Comment: why did you used `User Details/` a / at the end?

Comment: `getUser() { 
this.itemsRef = this.afdb.list('/Users/'+this.id+'/User Details');
this.items = this.itemsRef.snapshotChanges().map(changes => { 
 return changes.map(c =>  c.data) 
}) 
}`

Comment: I removed the '/' at the end but I still get the same error I sent you earlier.

Comment: ok can you post the image of the supported methods on the `itemsRef` variable using vs code?

Comment: What do you mean by supported methods? this is an image of my code: https://imgur.com/a/yOAKkHo

Comment: This is an image of a code that is not working right?
If you press `Ctrl+space` after `this.itemsRef.` you could see the list of supported methods, i just need the screenshot of that

Comment: yes, if it's clicked after the `.`
and show me the methods rather than all the possibilities look at my image and the methods icons
https://imgur.com/a/iJa4Avh

Comment: I clicked after the '.' in the list I sent you.

Comment: yes, but look at the icons of the methods, what you send me is all the possible things but not the methods, if you could scroll up/down on that list you can see all the methods

Comment: I looked up and down and couldn't find anything for after 'this.itemsRef.' but I did it after snapshotChanges() and got this: https://imgur.com/a/4HotZLC

Comment: well that is not helpful, since in your particular case it is mentioned that snapShotChanges() doesn't exist. We need to look what are all the supported methods by itemsRef

Comment: or the same could be done after putting a . after this.afdb.list() to see what are all the methods is supported

Comment: Can you any snapshot changes method in this? If so it is supported and if not please look into any other methods, I don't know why your particular list doesn't support snapshot changes though

Comment: I don't see any snapshot methods so I am assuming I can't, so I will try to look into other methods.

Comment: Well you do that, but I still don't know why in your particular case that was no help. Glad I could help you in some ways.

Comment: Also maybe I should have mentioned this before but this problem occurred when I changed my storing method from : https://imgur.com/a/wMhYpqb to https://imgur.com/a/aId57Fb

Comment: what if you changed back ?

Comment: Thats the thing every since I changed it even when I tried to change it back it still wouldn't work. But for my other firebase objects still work fine.

Comment: Can you check if I am displaying my data correctly? this is my html: https://imgur.com/a/LS5niYX , my ts:https://imgur.com/a/NYO5vXJ and this is how my data looks https://imgur.com/a/DE8WiMR

Comment: My initial problem was not an error it was just that the data is not displaying so I am assuming that it is not being retrieved correctly.

Comment: I think you may need to look at adding the correct way and retrieve the data the correct way, as mentioned in the docs, becuase I dont know why you are not seeing onSnapShotChanges method

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198178/discussion-on-answer-by-kevin-red-having-trouble-retreiving-data-from-firebase).

Comment: Sorry about that but it said that one of them had to low reputation to start a chat.